# Building string from table data using select query/pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a table with data in below format. Month wise counts data is provided in the last 3 columns.

```
Rep_Name   months  year  checkin hours teamsize
--------------------------------------------------------- 
aaa_aaaurf  4      2013     184  3      3
aaa_aaaurf  8      2013     0    3      1
aaa_access  11     2013     10   27     11
aaa_access  12     2013     12   12     11
```

I need to build a string which looks like below

```
Name :aaa_aaaurf,
Checkins:[[1,0],[2,0],[3,0],[4,3],[5,0],[6,0],[7,0],[8,3],[9,0],[10,0],[11,0],[12,0]],
hours:[[1,0],[2,0],[3,0],[4,184],[5,0],[6,0],[7,0],[8,0],[9,0],[10,0],[11,0],[12,0]],
teamsize:[[1,0],[2,0],[3,0],[4,3],[5,0],[6,0],[7,0],[8,3],[9,0],[10,0],[11,0],[12,0]]
```

This string is only for year 2013, and rep_name aaa_aaaurf. i need it to replicate for each rep_name ,each year. Can a pivot be used in this case? or should i use for loops to build such a string?

Comment: Do this in your application.

Comment: Building strings and SQL Server should not be permitted in the same sentence (except if it's dynamic SQL :-).

Comment: Maybe it's obvious to you, but don't assume we understand what those [,] combinations are. Edit your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heed the words of @AaronBertrand.

Being an utter moron, I have caved in to the whining of my lazy application developers requesting such nonsense be handled on the database side, despite my attempts to explain to them that databases are for the storage of [well-structured](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_data) data and are not particularly good at string packing anyway.  What you are trying to do here is the first step in making your database application-dependent and is generally considering poor form across the board, leading to a place where your stored data is no longer usable outside of the original application ( so, no reporting ) and very, very quickly becomes a complete maintenance nightmare.

If, on the off chance, you are doing this for yourself and in **no way will this ever make its sorry excuse for T-SQL into a production environment**, here is an example of how to do this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT  1
                FROM    sys.objects
                WHERE   name = 't_Pack' 
                    AND type = 'U' )
BEGIN
    --DROP TABLE dbo.t_Pack;
    CREATE TABLE dbo.t_Pack
    (
        Rep_Name        VARCHAR( 16 ),
        months          INTEGER,
        year            INTEGER,
        checkin         INTEGER,
        hours           INTEGER,
        teamsize        INTEGER
    );

    INSERT INTO dbo.t_Pack ( Rep_Name, months, year, checkin, hours, teamsize )
    SELECT  Rep_Name, months, year, checkin, hours, teamsize
    FROM (      SELECT  Rep_Name = NULL, 
                        months = NULL, 
                        year = NULL, 
                        checkin = NULL, 
                        hours = NULL, 
                        teamsize = NULL 
    UNION ALL   SELECT  'aaa_aaaurf', 4, 2013, 184, 3, 3
    UNION ALL   SELECT  'aaa_aaaurf', 8, 2013, 0, 3, 1
    UNION ALL   SELECT  'aaa_access', 11, 2013, 10, 27, 11
    UNION ALL   SELECT  'aaa_access', 12, 2013, 12, 12, 11 ) l
    WHERE   Rep_Name IS NOT NULL;
END;
GO

DECLARE @RepName        VARCHAR( 16 ),
        @CheckInString  VARCHAR( MAX ),
        @HoursString    VARCHAR( MAX ),
        @TeamSizeString VARCHAR( MAX ),
        @FinalString    VARCHAR( MAX );
    SET @RepName = 'aaa_aaaurf';

DECLARE @t_Months       TABLE
(
    MonthID             TINYINT
);

INSERT INTO @t_Months( MonthID )
VALUES ( 1 ), ( 2 ), ( 3 ), ( 4 ), ( 5 ), ( 6 ), ( 7 ), ( 8 ), ( 9 ), ( 10 ), ( 11 ), ( 12 );

SELECT  @CheckInString = ISNULL( @CheckInString, 'Checkins:[' )
            + '[' + LEFT( mth.MonthID, 10 ) + ',' + LEFT( ISNULL( p.checkin, 0 ), 10 ) + '],',
        @HoursString = ISNULL( @HoursString, 'hours:[' )
            + '[' + LEFT( mth.MonthID, 10 ) + ',' + LEFT( ISNULL( p.hours, 0 ), 10 ) + '],',
        @TeamSizeString = ISNULL( @TeamSizeString, 'teamsize:[' )
            + '[' + LEFT( mth.MonthID, 10 ) + ',' + LEFT( ISNULL( p.teamsize, 0 ), 10 ) + '],'
FROM    @t_Months mth
LEFT JOIN dbo.t_Pack p
    ON  mth.MonthID = p.months
    AND p.Rep_Name = @RepName
ORDER BY mth.MonthID;

    SET @FinalString = 'Name:' + @RepName + ',' + CHAR( 10 )
            + LEFT( @CheckInString, LEN( @CheckInString ) - 1 ) + '],' + CHAR( 10 )
            + LEFT( @HoursString, LEN( @HoursString ) - 1 ) + '],' + CHAR( 10 )
            + LEFT( @TeamSizeString, LEN( @TeamSizeString ) - 1 ) + ']';

PRINT   @FinalString;
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.t_Pack;
GO
```